# Using @media for my page and now i'm getting a side blank page that arounds the background when I look it in my mobile

Tags: html, css, media-queries

So im new using the medias queries, It looks good in my web browser (chrome) when I resize it to differents sizes, but when I look at my web in the phone it appears like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BVJp.jpg).

here's the web: http://www.wagrita.ml/

Comment: Just you have include image inside li tag and then adjust space I have added structure below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update space as per design

```css
.navbar-parent {
    background-color: rgba(247, 107, 138, .6);
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    height: 50px;
}

.navbar-child {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-right: 25px;
}
.navbar-child a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 1368px){
  .navbar-child li {
      display: flex;
      margin-left: 60px;
  }
  .navbar-child img {
      width: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-parent">
        <div class="title-container">
            <div class="navbar-title">
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="navbar-child">
            
            <li><img src="./img/home.svg"><a href="#">INICIO</a></li>
            
            <li><img src="./img/male.svg"><a href="#">CONTACTO</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must delete margin-left in these lines:

```
@media (max-width: 1368px)
.navbar-child img {
 /* margin-left: 135px; */
    width: 6%;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px)
.navbar-child img {
   /* margin-left: 75px; */
    width: 8%;
}
@media (max-width: 720px)
.navbar-child img {
   /* margin-left: 20px; */
}
```